# Reindexing error in Solr Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I'm having a Rails application which uses Solr Sunspot. The application was working fine. But now when I try to reindex it says

```
"Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error - retrying...
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error - ignoring...
[#################################################################] [50/50] [100.00%] [00:00] [00:00] [471.10/s]"
```

I tried deleting the Solr folder and restarting the Solr engine but it still has the same error.

Comment: Can you check the solr logs? Post relevant information if posible.